Azure Key Vault version error in ASP.NET Framework 4.7.2
Attempting to retrieve Azure Key Vault secret in C# / ASP.NET (.NET 4.7.2) app. I get this error

The specified version (7.5) is not recognized. Consider using the latest supported version (7.1)

Error
I have AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET and AZURE_TENANT_ID set as environmental variables. The required Access Policy has been granted for our Service Principal in Azure Stack Hub portal.
I tried setting the Version # in the code but it is a read-only property.
Code
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using System;

namespace KeyVaultNS
{
    public class KeyVault
    {
        public static string GetSecrets(string keyVaultURL, string secretKey)
        {
            var kvUri = $"https://example.com";
            string sKey = "TestKeyValue";
            var options = new SecretClientOptions() { DisableChallengeResourceVerification = true };
            //options.Version = "v1";
            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential(), options);
            var secret = client.GetSecret(sKey);
            return secret.ToString();
        }
    }
}


Please share the code as text format

I have tried the alternative in C# 8.0 version to retrieve the secret value of key vault by using below code:
Code:
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
 
namespace KVSecret
{
    class Secret
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string clientId = "appId";
            const string tenantId = "tenantId";
            const string clientSecret = "secret";
            var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://demokv2105.vault.azure.net"), credentials);
            var secret = client.GetSecretAsync("secret").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine(secret.Value.Value);
        }
    }
}

Output:


The package  Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets has been installed.

App.config:
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>


Thanks! I get the same error on the line assigning the value to var secret. "The specified version (7.5) is not recognized. Consider using the latest supported version (7.1)."

Can you create console application in .net 8.0 version and try the above code which i have shared.

We do not have plans to upgrade from .NET Framework at this time. I think there is some compatability issue with the way our org has Azure Key Vault set up and .NET Framework. So we are just going to use User Secrets for local development and release pipeline variables for deployment.

I have tried in ASP.NET framework 4.7.2 also got the same result which I gave in the above solution. Verify that the framework has installed in the VS Installer correctly.
